# ASP.NET MVC 3 Areas working locally but not on server, returns 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Happy New Year SO users!  I have an issue that I hope someone can help me with.

**The steps that got me here:**

An ASP.NET Web Site was converted to a Web Application (this works).

Then MVC libraries were added to the Web Application via the web.config file.

An MVC controller, view and routing entry were added manually (this works - able to see the default blue page).

I then MANUALLY added an Areas folder and supporting folders / files including the AreaRegistration class (manually as well)  [Note:  I have to add the MVC stuff (like an Area) manually because using the usual right-click context dialog box is not available]

**The problem:**

The non-Areas controller / view AND the Areas controller / view work fine on my local pc, but return a 404 error on the server.  Why?  What do I need to do to get this working?

**Other Information**

Local IIS version 7.5

Server IIS version = 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by the proper registration of Routes in the Global.asax.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming i read this right, the non-areas stuff is the stuff controlled by the mvc controller? If so, I have a stupid question. Did you verify the dll files are present on the webserver?

Also, working with both ASP.NET and MVC id suggest just rewriting the whole thing using mvc instead of reworking an old project.

Comment: Yes, the assemblies are registered in the GAC on server. Rewriting it in MVC would be nice.. but we live in a time sensitive society.

Comment: Even the conversion process would take a long time to debug and ensure that it works since you have to create the controllers and service classes to support them.
There are features with mvc that would make this process easier, such as the use of view models and strongly typed views and templates.
Youll have to do a cost-benefit analysis  to determine if a straight upgrade vs Green fields solution would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleanup following directories as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313571/arearegistration-registerallareas-is-not-registering-rules-for-area) and rebuild project

C:\Temp
C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
Path\To\Your\Project\obj\Debug