# AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() is not Registering Rules For Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC 4 web application which consists some areas. I have a problem with the routing rules of an area named "Catalog". The RouteConfig.cs file is:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        );
    }
```

and Global.asax as follows:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

And CatalogAreaRegistration is something like this:

```
public class CatalogAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Catalog";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Catalog_default",
            "Catalog/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is when i debug, RouteCollection routes does not include rules that are defined in the area. I used routedebugger and saw that routes collection does not consists rules of "Catalog" area. It has only rules in the RouteConfig.

I have no idea what is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you add `area = "Catalog"` to the defaults of the `MapRoute` call in the `RegisterArea` method?

Comment: @asymptoticFault i tried but it does not matter since rule in the RegisterArea, does not exist in the global routes.

Comment: In other words, if i add a break point in the RegisterArea method, it never hits. However, AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() called inside the global.asax

Comment: Clean you app. Rebuild your app and try again.

Comment: Cleaned, rebuilded, restarted, deleted the temp files, tried different pc... I think i'm overlooking something. :(

Comment: Have you had a look through this?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx  Didn't see anything in there though about creating area specific routes.

Comment: Nope. Nothing came up.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's the problem in this case, but I've seen a few people on our team tripped up by this recently when creating AreaRegistrations outside the root web app project...Make sure your AreaRegistration class is `public`. Thought it might be worth a mention here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think due to Visual Studio's caching, some of the dll's aren't compiled properly and this situation can happen. If you do, delete all temp files from following locations:

- C:\Temp
- C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- Path\To\Your\Project\obj\Debug

Update :

- AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Then restart the Visual Studio. This is how i resolved.

Comment: Deleted all my user settings.......Annoying, side effects like that should not result in the answer being selected in my opinion. :( And did not fix the issue for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the namespace of your controllers to the AreaRegistration:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            **namespaces: new string[] { "Web.Admin.Controllers" }**
        );
    }
```