# MVC 4 Area Routing is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I created an empty MVC4 Application, all things are working fine, after that I add an Area to my Project Named "Moderator". My area routing code is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace EskimoArt.Areas.Moderator
{
    public class ModeratorAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Moderator";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Moderator_default",
                "Moderator/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller="Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And my Global.asx code is like this:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace EskimoArt
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

But now I want to access the

```
> http://localhost/Moderator/Dashboard
```

It shows an Error Page like this

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Moderator

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Comment: Do you have any controllers in your area?

Comment: Yes I have controller in My Area. I figure out the problem by below option which is that Just call AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); before your default Route

Comment: Keep reading below - check the namespace of your controller(s)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. You look to App_Start/RouteConfig.cs and add top this code AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Create create Areas/Moderator/Controllers/DashboardController.cs

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Moderator/Dashboard/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and create

Areas/Moderator/Views/Dashboard/Index.cshtml

You also need to have Web.config in Areas/Moderator/Views/Web.config ...

Answer (score 14):

**Check the `namespace` of your controller.**

I had moved some code into an area and the namespace was still showing the old location.

ReSharper has a very cool option to fix the namespaces of all files in the folder, project or solution!  It is very handy to fix this.

Comment: More specifically check that the namespace in your controller matches the registered namespace in the `MapRoute` . Something like `namespace Project.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers` matches `namespaces: new[] { "Project.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers"}`

Answer (score 1):

Just try to delete content from following directories as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313571/arearegistration-registerallareas-is-not-registering-rules-for-area) and rebuild project

> C:\Temp C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files Path\To\Your\Project\obj\Debug

Answer (score 1):

Its better to add

> AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

in global.asax.cs. You must place in following order.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

Note one things that RegisterAllAreas() should be after Registering the routes.
ie. `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` should be before `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` .I have tried and tested and it worked for me.

For more info: [enter link description here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2103213.aspx?Mvc%20Area%20Issue%20with%20attribute%20Routing)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the "namespace:" named parameter in `RegisterRoutes()` method of `RouteConfig.cs` in `App_Start` folder. And specify the value of "namespace" to the namespace of your controller, within which you want to call action method.
In following example i want to call `Index()` method in Village Controller from root of project.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Village", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "MvcApplication1.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in project properties > Web > Start Action > if a specific page | action | url is defined, it does match with mapped routes.