# Routing not working in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have problems with the routing for my razor mvc 4 site.

The Newssite is in a custom area, here ist the `NewsAreaRegistration`

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Web.Areas.News {
    public class NewsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration {
        public override string AreaName {
            get {
                return "News";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) {
            context.MapRoute(
                name: "News",
                url: "news/read/{news}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", news = "" },
                namespaces: new[] { "Web.Areas.News.Controllers" }
            );
            context.MapRoute(
                name: "News_default",
                url: "news/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", news = "" },
                namespaces: new[] { "Web.Areas.News.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the controller

```
namespace Web.Areas.News.Controllers {

    public class HomeController : Controller {
        private DataModel websiteModel = new DataModel();

        //
        // GET: /News/
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index(string news = "") {
            if (!websiteModel.NewsExists(news))
                return View("Index");
            else
                return View("Read", new NewsModel(websiteModel.GetNews(news.ToLower())));
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Read(string news = "") {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { news = news });
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to access `http://localhost/news/` I just get a 404. Any ideas how to fix it?

**EDIT** Early I had it in my `RouteConfig`, there it worked fine. After a small refactor, I moved the three areas I have, Home, Admin and News, in seperated Areas, now only the news don't work, the rest works fine.

The News were earlier in the `HomeAreaRegistration` this looked like that:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Web.Areas.Home {
    public class HomeAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration {
        public override string AreaName {
            get {
                return "Home";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) {
            context.MapRoute(
                name: "News",
                url: "News/Read/{news}",
                defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Index", news = "" },
                namespaces: new[] { "Web.Controllers" }
            );
            context.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Web.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2** The page is running on my local IIS, not IIS Express and on port 80.

**EDIT 3** The `NewsAreaRegistration` routes are all registered, I just could check it.

Comment: well first of all where do you run your application? you need to specify port... like this http://localhost:1547/news/

Comment: I would install glimpse from nuget, it has a great route debugger which will show you which route is being matched so you can find tune your route declarations

Comment: It runs on my local IIS. So port 80.

Comment: then your url must be http://localhost:80/news/ : )

Comment: Since when? It worked earlier. Stackoverflow runs on port 80 too and you don't need to type http://stackoverflow.com:80/

Comment: Did you tried to run your application in visual studio? if it runs then you have problem with IIS configuration becouse I tried it now in visual studio your routing configuration worked but in IIS it throws internal server error. And by the way try to change port 80, becouse another application may use this port in IIS... check it anyway

Comment: It works for every other part of the site in IIS, it worked before in IIS too, just when I moved it in the areas it stopped working. When I change it back it works again.

Comment: I tried in VS Development Server and it doesn't work eather. And sorry for the slightly strong language it is pretty early in germany ;)

Comment: And what is your controller name?

Comment: From your routing configuration you will be able to access your action methods only from HomeController, because of news/read/{news} and news/{action} urls...

Comment: Where do you mean? The Controller for the newssite is in the first codeblock.

Comment: How did then the second EDIT worked perfectly?

Comment: yes sorry didn't noticed it

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong with your code, checked it in IIS 7.5 and in visual studio works fine. Here is the link of my project that I created you can see it maybe it will help you http://www.filedropper.com/mvcapplication1

Comment: Would you maybe host it on github? I can't open it. I'm using VS 2012, Windows 8.1 and IIS8.

Comment: Are u specifying the area in your links?

Comment: See in my answer, I have a solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it, by this question: [MVC 4 Area Routing is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239995/mvc-4-area-routing-is-not-working)

The problem was, that the default route was registered **before** I registered the `News_default` and `News` routes.

I changed the code to this:

RouteConfig:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Web {

    public class RouteConfig {

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Web.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

`NewsAreaRegistration`

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Web.Areas.News {
    public class NewsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration {
        public override string AreaName {
            get {
                return "News";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) {
            context.MapRoute(
                name: "News",
                url: "news/read/{news}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", news = "" },
                namespaces: new[] { "Web.Areas.News.Controllers" }
            );
            context.MapRoute(
                name: "News_default",
                url: "news/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", news = "" },
                namespaces: new[] { "Web.Areas.News.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three things I see that could cause the issue you're having:

1. (more likely) is that you forgot your port number on your URL `http://localhost:portnumber]/News`. you can find your port number by opening the iis express in your taskbar.
2. iis Express is not running (Run your application in Visual Studio)
3. Can you try to replace your `news=""` with `news=UrlParameter.Optional` and see if this is your issue?

Hope this helps

Comment: Neither one, two or threee helped.