# AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() never finishes when using Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I created a new ASP.net MVC application using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and checked the box to use Application Insights. When I try and run the application (with or without debugging) the site never loads. When I debug it I noticed that it is getting stuck in Global.asax.cs on the line:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

I have taken a look at the answers on a few other questions including this one:
[AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() is not Registering Rules For Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313571/arearegistration-registerallareas-is-not-registering-rules-for-area)

This did not solve my issue. I have deleted all of the content in the folders in this answer and restarted visual studio, restarted my PC and no matter what I do this method just hangs forever. It doesn't appear to just be slow, because I have waited for over 5 minutes and it still hasn't finished. Has anyone else run into this scenario and how can I fix it other than removing this call?

It appears if I comment out the Http Module registration for Application Insights then this method finishes right away, but as soon as I add them back the method hangs again. There appears to be some problem with the AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() call and Application Insights.

```
<httpModules>
    <!-- removing this makes everything work -->
    <!-- <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" /> -->
</httpModules>

<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <!-- removing these makes things work -->
  <!-- 
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  -->
</modules>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue when registering areas from different projects, and it was caused by different versions of the same assembly i had in both host project and in the referenced project, like `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: @RaraituL This is a brand new project with no code other than what is created by the default MVC template.

Comment: Hmm, check `System.Web.Mvc` assembly. From the templates it gets created with a lower version of what exists on `nuget` right now. Try installing from `nuget` the latest version of `Microsoft ASP.NET MVC`

Comment: @RaraituL My MVC is up to date as far as NuGet is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes i have the same situation and what i have done is remove appinsight element and apply xml transformation between debug and release web.config file. This helps me when me want to debug and include appinsight when release.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"
           xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
    </httpModules>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I don't *need* App Insights to run while I am developing, but it's still annoying that I need to do this.

Comment: Yeah i have done fair bit of Googling but seem to be there is no one has found a solution yet. Anyone with some idea please?

Answer (score -1):

Could you provide more details, so we could reproduce this issue?

- What operating system do you use (Windows Version)?
- Are you running created web application on IIS Express or regular IIS?
- If this is regular IIS, what application pool mode do you use (integrated/classic)?
- What .NET Framework version you choose to create an application?
- What MVC version your application is based on?
- Did you enable WebAPI or WebForms for your web app project?

Comment: This does not answer the question.